# MongoDB aggregation query performing slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

> I am running following aggregation query on the collections with size:
>   1: all_api with 19382365 documents
>   2: edge_api with 8250124 documents
>   **Query:**

```
db.getCollection('edge_api').aggregate([{
    $match: {
      state: {
        $eq: 'rj'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "all_api",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "edge_id",
      as: "road_speed"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      path: "$road_speed"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      road_code: "$road_code",
      speed: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [{
              case: {
                $gt: ["road_speed.saving_time", 1535349227]
              },
              then: "$road_speed.spd_cur"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $lte: ["road_speed.saving_time", 1535349227]
              },
              then: "$road_speed.spd_pro"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      speed: {
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "road_code": {
        $first: "$road_code"
      },
      "speed": {
        "$avg": "$speed"
      }
    }
  }
], {
  allowDiskUse: true,
  cursor: {
    batchSize: 10000000000
  }
});
```

It took around 40 to 50 seconds to execute.
Which is not acceptable, in case of an api response.
Is there anything that i can do to make this query performance batter.
If somebody have any suggestions regarding this, please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: For: all_api
{
    "_id" : 1
}
{
    "saving_time" : 1
}

{
    "edge_id" : 1
}

For: edge_api
{
    "_id" : 1
}
{
    "state" : 1
}

Comment: Have you tried using $explain https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/?

Comment: Hi Akrion, Following is the query plan for this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O38D0A4UB-m0gbvVu8fs5acz6J5A3FF9/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: can you provide samples of your collections?

Comment: @SachinKr.Saini slow queries are typically caused by underprovisioned hardware. Your query also contains $lookup (expensive) and $group (expensive). How is your server provisioned? How much RAM do you have, and what's the output of `db.all_api.stats()` and `db.edge_api.stats()`?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha, we have 16 GB RAM on database server.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha, And the collection stats are as follows in this link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZMjqEkNKa3EA8UXxCKdyfg_t2lcrBE-V/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @SachinKr.Saini your `all_api` collection is 11 GB, and your `edge_api` is 5 GB. The two collections combined (without counting indexes) is the size of your whole RAM. Simply put, the query is slow because it operates on large collections, and thus necessitates paging data in & out of disk to do the work. Rough calculation, you'd need a server with at least 4x the RAM to do the work faster. Having faster disk would also help.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha, We have 3 db servers in replication with 16 GB RAM and 8 Cores on each, will this make any impact on query.

Comment: @SachinKr.Saini if each server run a single `mongod`, it will generally not impact queries. However this depends on how busy the server is, what other queries you run, how many inserts you're doing, etc. If you run multiple `mongod` on a single server, this will severely impact performance.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha, yes, app_api collection having around 5-8 millions updations at every 2 mins, and other collections also having updations on same database. than what kind of provisioning we can do with database.

Comment: @KevinAdistamba, I more thing, which I observed is that, when we run lookup using standalone mongodb instance it is taking around 1 second, but in replication it takes 5 to 20 seconds, and the second thing when I applied projection on lookup data using switch statements on all_api fields it becomes slow, I think this is happened because of the lookup information not using indexes at the time of switch case statements. am I right or there is anything else?

Comment: @SachinKr.Saini note that this discussion is running away from the original question, to which the answer is your hardware is underprovisioned. In terms of questions about provisioning, this is not the right venue for this. It's best if you lay out all the facts in a question in dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KevinAdistambha, Ok i will, and thanks for the valuable answers.

Comment: @Akrion, I have tried tried.

Comment: Yes, i have tried.